# How to click text area in Qwebview and python

Tags: javascript, python, qwebview, qwebelement

I am using QWebView with python to create an automate application and I could select Qwebelements by tags and id, also it's easy to click buttons but I can't do the following 
- click elements with tag "Textarea" to prepare them to insert data
- send keys to textrea elements

the code example for what I can do to fill a form is below but it doesn't work for textarea elements

```
page = webview.page().mainFrame()
doc = page.documentElement()
username = doc.findFirst("input[id=email]")
username.setAttribute('value', "user@user.com")
password = doc.findfirst("input[id=pass]")
bt.evaluateJavaScript('this.click()')
```

#this one after getting button element as above ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Element focusing:**

You're trying to 'focus' an element, meaning that input goes to that element. 
to focus, just try this:

```
txtarea = self.documentElement.findFirst('textarea[name="someTextArea"]')
txtarea.evaluateJavascript('this.focus()')
```

**Setting Attributes vs Properties:**
The most straightforward way to do this is just set the value of the 'textarea' using JavaScript (instead of setting the attribute directly).

Example:

```
txtarea = self.documentElement.findFirst('textarea[name="someTextArea"]')
txtarea.evaluateJavaScript('this.value="' + yourText + '";')
```

**Some extra details:**

The reason 'setAttribute' didn't work for you: 
you're trying to change the **Attribute** called 'value', whereas what you should actually change is the **Property** 'value'. 
the difference between the two is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but setattribute is working for me , what i am asking about is : when i get the element is to click it , for example the text area in facebook group i can find it but got error when trying to click it so it opened and the button "Post" appears

Comment: Oh, 

I think what you're trying to do is "focus" the element then. 

I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

for focusing text area element like "facebook group text area" use "txtarea.evaluateJavaScript("this.focus()") instead of "this.click()" 
this worked for me